# How can I create queue that can use in Breadth-first-search?

Tags: c, tree, queue, breadth-first-search

This is an example of my code, I create node from the tree

```
typedef struct _treenode
{
  int data;
  struct _treenode* left;
  struct _treenode* right; 
}TREENODE_T;


int main(void) {
  //create node
  TREENODE_T* N1 = newNodeCreate(9);
  TREENODE_T* N2 = newNodeCreate(6);
  TREENODE_T* N3 = newNodeCreate(10);

  //set child node
  int status;
  status = setChildNote(N1, N2, 'L');
  status = setChildNote(N1, N3, 'R');

  QUEUE_T* queue=queueCreate(10);
  breadthSearch(root,queue);
```

But I don't know how to create a queue that can stack TREENODE_T*. What should I do?

Comment: A linked list would easily work as a queue. Append to the tail. Remove from the head. ("Queue" is a French word that literally means "tail".)

Comment: `TREENODE_T *` is a pointer, so you can store the queue entries in an array of pointers, e.g. `TREENODE_T *queueArray[MAXQ]`. If you want a queue that works with any type of pointer, create an array of void pointers, e.g. `void *queueArray[MAXQ]`.